# Static golang build of app using cgo library

Tags: go, build, static-libraries

I've decided to use zstd library for compression in my code using the [Go wrapper from datadog](https://github.com/DataDog/zstd).
My build command for app is (I build my app in gitlab-ci using `image: golang:1.10.2-alpine`)

```
dep ensure --vendor-only
CGO_ENABLE=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' cmd/main.go
```

Which fails with

```
build constraints exclude all Go files in /go/src/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/github.com/DataDog/zstd
```

When I try to enable `CGO_ENABLED` (and keep the rest of the build commands unchanged) I end up with warnings:

```
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000054.o: In function `mygetgrouplist':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/getgrouplist_unix.go:15: warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000053.o: In function `mygetgrgid_r':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:38: warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000053.o: In function `mygetgrnam_r':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:43: warning: Using 'getgrnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000053.o: In function `mygetpwnam_r':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:33: warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000053.o: In function `mygetpwuid_r':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:28: warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-395607750/000004.o: In function `_cgo_f7895c2c5a3a_C2func_getaddrinfo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:46: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Which doesn't seem ok as I want to have my build statically linked. Do I have to firstly build zstd library and then build my app?

Comment: The warnings are correct, you should not statically link to glibc. However, if you're building in an alpine container, why are you linking to glibc when alpine uses musl?

Comment: @JimB I am not really a sure how the link is being created to glibc. I run only the command above, I don't specify glibc anywhere.

Comment: I just double checked and the go binary is linked to musl libc the `go:alpine` container. Are you actually running that in the correct container? Why are you specifying `GOOS=linux` if you're already running on linux?

Comment: I checked my dockerfile and there indeed was a golang image instead of golang-alpine one (golang-alpine was being used only in gitlab-ci). That was really a stupid mistake and it didn't occur to me to check for it. Thank you for your help @JimB.